# How to solve this type of function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[This is an image of the question being asked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FIsB.png)

On top of that this is the question shown below:

```
                f[n]=((0.45)^n)*u[n-3]
                g[n]=f[n-4]
```

Solve for g[n]?

My question is can g[n] be represented as g[n] = f[n] + f[-4]
And then solved for, or am I off?

Comment: Just insert $(n-4)$ instead of $n$ in $f$ to get $f(n-4)$ which is $g(n)$

Comment: I want to ask is it possible to split it up that way? is g[n] = f[n] + f[-4] as valid as g[n] = f[n-4]

Comment: $f(n) + f(-4) = 0,45^n.u(n-3) + 0,45^{-4}.u(-7)$ which is not always equal to $g(n)$

Answer (score 1):

$$g(n) = f(n-4) = 0,45^{n-4}. u(n-7)$$